prevent certain line of code to not rollback after using @transaction annotation in spring
I have used a @transaction annotation in a function and when any exception occurs so that it rollback everything. I have a line of code that updates whether task failed or passed in DB that is inside that function. I don't want that action to rollback what to do?
@Transactional
public void performTransactionAndAddEntry() {
    
    try {

    /// my other task like writing in a file and creating a mail body and attachment etc


        // Calling the method to add an entry to the database
        addEntryToDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


I'm not quite sure what you're referring to but do you mean addEntryToDatabase(); should be called and successful even if what happens before in the try block fails? In that case that method would have to use its own transaction and it should be called in the finally block which doesn't exist yet (or you call it in the try and catch blocks if different parameters are required).

You cannot. A transaction is either successful fully or it isn't, it isn't partially correct. If you want something to persist regardless of the outcome of the other transaction do that in a new independent transaction.

If you need more fine-grained control over transaction status, consider using programmatic transactions instead of declarative annotations. You can use Spring’s TransactionTemplate or directly interact with the PlatformTransactionManager. This approach allows you to manipulate the transaction status explicitly.
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

public void performTransactionAndAddEntry() {
    try {
        // Other tasks (e.g., writing to a file, creating a mail body)
        // ...

        // Add an entry to the database (without triggering rollback)
        transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            addEntryToDatabase();
            return null;
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


so you explicitly want to save/update data while using @Transactional annotation..
so for that you need to use predefined JPA's flush method for example...
@Transactional
public void performTransactionAndAddEntry() {
    
    try {

    /// my other task like writing in a file and creating a mail body and attachment etc


       //lets say below is your save or update method
       repository.save();
       
       //after save or update just use flush
       repository.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

for more info you can check the link
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-flush

Assuming we are talking about spring @transactional.
When you write the method to save the entry to the DB use the following propagation method:
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void addEntryToDatabase(){
    //Your code
}

Also the roll back occurs due to an exception, so better to put the call in the finally block.
finally{
   addEntryToDatabase();
} 

